# How do you get an equation to output an answer as a decimal?

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment for class, and I have got just about everything. It's simply supposed to take the width and height of a box and output the area as well as how much paint is necessary. I can get the first three parts but it will only tell me how much paint is necessary if it is a multiple of 400 (the number being used to determine how much paint is necessary).

I currently have this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int wallHeight, wallWidth, wallArea;

      cout << "Please enter the height of the wall (feet): ";
    cin >> wallHeight;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the width of the wall (feet): ";
    cin >> wallWidth;

    wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
    const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400;

    cout << endl << "The area of the wall is: " << wallArea << " square feet. "
         << "This will require about " << paintNeeded << " gallons of paint." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Say I put in that the wall is 24x2. It will say the area is 48, but that it requires 0 gallons of paint, I just want it to say it requires 0.12 gallons.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not make `wallHeight, wallWidth, wallArea` `double`s instead of `int`s?

Comment: #include <iomanip> setprecision(2), fixed, etc. look into those

Comment: Eh? 'As a decimal'? Do you mean 'with a fractional part'?

Answer (score 1):

Cast `wallArea` as double:

```
const double paintNeeded = (double)wallArea / 400;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ if `a` and `b` are both integers then `a/b` is computed using integer arithmetic.

In your code the computation:

```
 const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400;
```

will perform the division using integer arithmetic before placing the result (0) into a `double`.

Changing the code to:

```
 const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400.;
```

(note the dot after 400) will perform the division using floating point arithmetic, giving the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having here is that you are doing an operation on 2 integers. This results in the final value to be stored as an int with zero decimal points.

Here, you have the following line:

```
    int wallHeight, wallWidth, wallArea;
```

where you have declared your 3 main variables as type `int`. Then in the following line, you conduct the following operation:

```
    const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400;
```

Here, even though you store the quotient of `wallArea / 400` in a variable of type `double`, the division itself is between the 2 integers, because `wallArea` is an `int` variable, and 400 is also processed as an `int` value because there is no decimal value after it.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

### Option 1: Change the value of 400 so that it is processed as an int

This is possibly the simplest way, but it gives you no control over how many decimal spaces you want to output. This can be simply done by changing the following line:

```
    const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400;
```

to:

```
    const double paintNeeded = wallArea / 400.0;
```

The only difference here is that the 400 is now processed as a value of data type `float`. This way, when you run the following line:

```
        cout << endl << "The area of the wall is: " << wallArea << " square feet. "
             << "This will require about " << paintNeeded << " gallons of paint." << endl;
```

paintNeeded will output `0.12` instead of 0.

### Option 2: Use Casting

This is the alternative to changing 400 to 400.0; here you cast the variable `wallArea` to be processed as a double. See this line:

```
    const double paintNeeded = (double)wallArea / 400;
```

Here, you force the compiler to make a conversion of the value stored in wallArea to a type double. This is risky in some situations (not yours), because if a conversion is not possible (from type int to string for example), then it will cause an error. However, in your case, converting an int to type double is doable here, so in effect, a double value is divided by 400 with no errors. This, in effect, has the same result as the first choice; output `paintNeeded` with a decimal point. This case also results in an output for `paintNeeded` equal to `0.12` instead of 0.

---

These 2 methods are by far the best for your situation, because you do not want to output a specific number of decimal places, . If, however, you are interested in another way of doing it, you can use `setprecision(int precision_value)` from the `#include <iomanip>` header file. For more information on this, visit [std::setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).